# Rails 3 CanCan HTML Helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, html-helper, cancan

I'm using stanard rails HTML helpers

```
<%= form_for @person do |f| %>
 <%= f.label :first_name %>:
 <%= f.text_field :first_name %><br />
<%end%>
```

But lets say I want to de-activate the text_field if if first_name is not editable by the current user.  So CanCan says I can do this

```
<%= f.text_field :name if can? :update, @person, :first_name %>
```

This is fine and dandy, but I would like to abstract this somehow similar to:

```
<%= f.conditional_text_field :first_name %>
```

In this example, my custom built HTML helper knows I'm talking about a @person because the it is in the form helper via f.object.  I like this because the re-factored handling of un-editable attributes can be centrally controlled.  I could opt to display a disabled input box, or I could render the text.  If nothing else I have a convenient hook to update authorization if CanCan changes, is replaced by something in the future, or I want to hook in some crazy workflow thing.

1. Does this look like a good idea?
2. Is there a gem for this already?

---

Update

I'm currently looking at adding a helper as follows:

```
def can_text_field(f, field, *args)
  field = field.to_sym
  if can? :update, f.object, field
    return f.text_field field.to_sym *args
  else
    if can? :read, f.object, field
      return f.object.send(field)
    else
      return "Not Authorized"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with updating FormHelper

```
class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder

  alias :original_text_field :text_field
  def text_field(method, options = {})
    if @@current_ability.cannot? :update, self.object, method.to_sym
      options[:disabled]="disabled"
    end
    self.original_text_field(method, options)
  end

  alias :origianl_collection_select :collection_select
  def collection_select(method, collection, id_method, display_method,
                        options={}, html_options={})
    if @@current_ability.cannot? :update, self.object, method.to_sym
      html_options[:disabled]="disabled"
    end
    self.original_collection_select(method, collection, id_method,
                                    display_method, options, html_options)
  end

  def self.set_current_ability(current_ability)
    @@current_ability = current_ability
  end

end
```

I had to add a controller before_filter to load the FormBuilder with current_ability

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_ability

  private

  def set_current_ability
    ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder.set_current_ability( current_ability )
  end
end
```